# Wake Laptop if lid is opend (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, linux-mint, hibernate

I'd like to know why MacOS detects when the laptop's lid is opened and automatically wakes, while Ubuntu does not (I am using Linux Mint currently).

So my questions are:

1. When I close lid under MacOS, does it hibernate or just suspend? I suppose it is hibernate since the power consumption is quite low.
2. Under Linux distros such as Ubuntu or Mint, how can we achieve the same thing? I would like that when I open the lid, it can recover directly from hibernate instead of having to press the power button and load GRUB.

Comment: Do you mean why "Mac OS" can detect the lid's state?

Comment: yes, especially when lid is opened, and also when it closed, is it hibernated or just suspended ?

Comment: Please edit your question then. "Mac" is the computer, the hardware. "Mac OS" is the software. In your case you are wondering why Mac OS can detect the state of the lid but Ubuntu cannot. Both of these OSes are running on the Mac. Also, focus on your actual question: How do I get Ubuntu to change power states based on the lid being open or closed on your Macbook.

Comment: On my Lenovo Ubuntu(*) detects the lid (and wakes up is configured to do so). Do you have a file: `/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state` (likely provided by some hardware driver). (16.04, but worked with 14.04, 12.04 and 10.04 on my previous two computers).

Comment: macOS just "sleeps" (probably more like "suspend to RAM" in other OSes) when you close the lid. If the battery level drops below a certain point, it'll write out RAM to disk and hibernate. When you wake your Mac, if you see a grey screen image while a multi-segment progress "bar" fills in, you know it's waking from hibernation. If you don't see that, then it wasn't hibernation. I *imagine* that the hall effect sensor (the magnet sensor than senses when the lid is closed) is connected to the SMC (System Management Controller), so the SMC can wake the system when the magnet is no longer nearby.

Comment: @xenoid Yes, I have this state file. So how do you make use of it ?

Comment: @music2myear, actually I would like to do it on a laptop(Spectre x360) instead of Macbook, I have updated the question, thanks

Comment: I assume that if it's there it is used. You can test that it works with a quick bash: `for i  in {1..10};do cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state;sleep 5;done`. Start it, let it print one line, close the lid, wait 10s, reopen, you should see open/open/closed/closed/closed/open... Otherwise as in AskUbuntu. Your desktop (Gnome/KDE/Unity...) may also be a factor.

Comment: Ok, in that case the parts about MacOS are a distraction and not relevant to the actual question. Windows laptops have the same function, and every laptop I've run linux flavors on has detected lid state just fine and allowed me to control what happens. I'd advise removing everything about MacOS in your question.

Comment: Have you been through these solutions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763085/with-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-doesnt-suspend-when-lid-is-closed and https://askubuntu.com/questions/395428/laptop-does-not-suspend-when-lid-is-closed/427193#427193